# How do I stack multiple pictures on top of each other and have text on the sides of them?

Tags: html, css

I am basically trying to mimic the Youtube sidebar to watch the next video. It's static so just HTML and CSS, but I have tried floating it and the next image just floats next to the previous image. Any suggestions?

```css
.sideBar {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 337px;
  height: 900px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.video-thumbnail img {
  width: 168px;
  height: 94px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.videoText {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">
  <h4>Up Next</h4>
  <br>
  <div class="recommended-videos">
    <div class="video-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://i">
    </div>
    <div class="videoText">
      <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
      <h6>ipsum lorem</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recommended-videos">
    <div class="video-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://i.y">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add a container and set overflow to hidden;

See this modified code

```
<div class="sideBar">
   <h4>Up Next</h4>
   <br>
  <div class="recommended-videos">
    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="video-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i">
      </div>
      <div class="videoText">
        <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
        <h6>ipsum lorem</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="video-container">
      <div class="video-thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i">
      </div>
      <div class="videoText">
        <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
        <h6>ipsum lorem</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sideBar {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 337px;
  height: 900px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.video-thumbnail img {
  width: 168px;
  height: 94px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.videoText {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.video-container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But i am still confused as to why. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: When using floats, the wrapper container will not have the height of the floated elements. Two ways to make the parent have a height is by doing overflow hidden or adding a clearfix. 

If video-container has a height, then the containers will stack on each other and not wrap around.

Answer (score 0):

Although this will give you the results you are expecting, I have some recommendations.

I would avoid:

- Using heading elements here, use CSS instead
- Unnecessary nesting of elements

It may be beneficial to take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) to aid in styling your HTML.

```css
.sideBar {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 337px;
  height: 900px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.video img {
  width: 168px;
  height: 94px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.videoText {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">
  <h4>Up Next</h4>
  <br>
  <div class='video'>
    <img src="https://i">
    <div class="videoText">
      <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
      <h6>ipsum lorem</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='video'>
    <img src="https://i">
    <div class="videoText">
      <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
      <h6>ipsum lorem</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps,